# Membership structure with 2 renewal cycles?

Tags: civimember

I need to implement the following membership structure, and am wondering if this is possible with civimember? I'm having some trouble seeing how this could work with fixed membership periods...

Thanks!

Ahna

Spring Renewal
- Joins/renews Jan 1 - Jun 30
- Renewal date is Mar 31 of following year
- Grace period extends through Jun 30, when non-renewals are removed from member roll

Fall Renewal
- Joins/renews Jul 1 - Dec 31
- Renewal date is Sept 30 of following year
- Grace period extends through Dec 31, when non-renewals are removed from member roll

Answer (score 1):

This is a strong point of CiviCRM - there's no system out there that supports all of the MANY different quirky membership structures that exist in the world - but CiviCRM makes it easy to write an extension to implement your particular structure.  That said, it DOES require that you write custom code, or hire someone who does.  You can use [civix](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension) to create a CiviCRM extension.  Most times, you can use [hook_civicrm_post](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_post), in some special cases you might want to use [hook_civicrm_alterCalculatedMembershipStatus](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_alterCalculatedMembershipStatus).